# GDF.simplify messes up geometries

Tags: geopandas, cartopy

I am trying to plot river basins on a map. In order to reduce the size of the resulting vector graphics, I am applying `GeoSeries.simplify()`.

```py
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd

# %%% Earth
fig = plt.figure()

latlon_proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()
axis_proj = ccrs.Orthographic()

ax = plt.axes(
    projection=axis_proj
    )

# %%% Major River Basins

mrb_basins = gpd.read_file('mrb_basins.json') # 520 entries

mrb_basins['geometry'] = mrb_basins['geometry'].simplify(0.1)

for shape in mrb_basins['geometry']:

    feat = cartopy.feature.ShapelyFeature(
        [shape],
        latlon_proj,
        facecolor='red',
        )

    ax.add_feature(feat)

mrb_basins.plot()
```

The problem is, the resulting map of the earth is fully covered by a red shape.

[image]

This is not the case, if I remove the line `mrb_basins['geometry'] = mrb_basins['geometry'].simplify(0.1)`.

[image]

How can I simplify the geometries whilst keeping their integrity?

The data set of major river basins is available [here](https://www.bafg.de/SharedDocs/ExterneLinks/GRDC/mrb_json_zip.html;jsessionid=7CC517A447063F8DBA969CC087E4A219.live21323?nn=201762).

Answer (score 1):

`GeoSeries.simplify()` does not always return valid geometries due to the underlying simplification algorithm used by GEOS. And cartopy has trouble to plot invalid geometries.

You need to fix your geometries before passing them to cartopy. The simple trick is to call `buffer(0)`.

```py
mrb_basins['geometry'] = mrb_basins['geometry'].simplify(0.1).buffer(0)
```

Then your code works fine.

[image: result]